# How do I know whether FileInputStream opens a file?

Tags: poco-libraries

I am using **Poco::FileInputStream** to design a copy function

```
void do_copy_file(Poco::FileInputStream & iss)
{
    Poco::FileOutputStream fos("output.txt");

    Poco::StreamCopier::copyStream(iss, fos);
}
```

Then, a user can call **do_copy_file** like this

```
Poco::FileInputStream fis;
do_copy_file(fis);
```

My question: Can I judge whether **iss** refers a valid file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Poco::FileOutputStream](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.FileOutputStream.html) just throws a Poco::FileException if an error occurs when trying to open it, e.g. if a invalid file path is used. It doesn't have any function to test whether it is valid.

What you could do is change your `do_copy_file()` function to catch an Poco::FileException exception and return a boolean value - true if opened successfully or false otherwise:

```
bool do_copy_file(Poco::FileInputStream & iss)
{
    bool result(true);

    try
    {
        Poco::FileOutputStream fos("output.txt");
        Poco::StreamCopier::copyStream(iss, fos);
    }
    catch (const Poco::FileException&)
    {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
Poco::FileInputStream fis;
if (do_copy_file(fis)
{
    //output file stream opened successfully
}
```

---

If you want `do_copy_file()` to catch an exception for opening the input stream I would recommend doing that in the function itself. Instead of passing the input streams pass the file paths instead:

```
bool do_copy_file(const std::string &inputFile, const std::string& outputFile)
{
    bool result(true);

    try
    {
        Poco::FileInputStream fis(inputFile);
        Poco::FileOutputStream fos(outputFile);
        Poco::StreamCopier::copyStream(fis, fos);
    }
    catch (const Poco::FileException&)
    {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: thank you. this could be the best answer after i tried so much

Comment: After I tried your solution, always return true, :(

Comment: @mac.ma Isn't that what you were expecting? It's succeeding then?

Comment: using **Poco::FileInputStream fis** will not produce exception, but **Poco::FileInputStream fis("./a_not_existed_file.txt")** will produce exception

Comment: @mac.ma Yes, that's true. If you want to catch an exception for the input stream, then why not do that in your function? Pass the file path of the input file instead of input stream.

Comment: Ok, I'll take your advice :)

Comment: **Poco::FileInputStream fis** will no more exist, very useful